# Python 3 KeyboardInterrupt Multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am trying to have a main thread wait for its worker threads to finish using the following code, but when I try to interrupt it with Ctrl+C it doesn't stop

```
import threading
import sys
exit = threading.Event()

#pass it to the threads

try:
    exit.wait()
    print('Goodbye')
    sys.exit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interrupted')
    sys.exit()
```

UPDATE
Nothing prints. All background threads are daemons.

Comment: There was a formatting error. Fixed

Comment: What platform are you on? On Linux or macOS (unless you're using 3.0-3.1, which are basically broken), I believe all `wait`s on `threading` objects should be interruptible by signals, and, once it's interrupted, Python will immediately process the SIGINT as a `KeyboardInterrupt`. But on Windows… I'm not sure how that works, but you may need something more.

Comment: Also, I assume the main thread _is_ still blocked on that `exit.wait()`, and hasn't yet printed `Goodbye'`, right? (Because otherwise, it's already left the `try`/`except` block, so obviously the `try` can't capture the exception.)

Comment: Daemon thread or not? Does `Interrupted` print?

Comment: I am on Windows. The main thread is still blocked. All my background threads are currently daemons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading
import sys
import time
exit = threading.Event()

#pass it to the threads

try:
    print("hi")
    time.sleep(20)
    print('Goodbye')
    sys.exit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interrupted')
    sys.exit()
```

Please try the above statement to test your code. i have tested it and its working fine for me.

As you are using exit.wait() without giving any timeouts, its running for infinite seconds. So please put some time as an agument. 
Follow the below code:

```
exit = threading.Event()

#pass it to the threads

try:
    print("hi")
    exit.wait(5)
    print('Goodbye')
    sys.exit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interrupted')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: I am trying to have the main thread wait indefinitely unless interrupted, ideally without simply have a while loop running checking for a flag.

Comment: Is that possible??

Comment: Thats possible if you will use Loops for that. But using Wait() its impossible.